# Hydrolysis of salt

Tags: acid-base, hydrolysis, salt

The hydrolysis of salt tells you whether a salt is acidic or basic. But it does not tell you how acidic or basic a salt is. Is there a way to determine this?

My guess is that taking of the weak base part of a salt( presuppose that it is acidic) and see how many hydronium ion it could produce. So the more hydronium ions, the more acidic this salt is?

Comment: Why not just use pKa or Ka values for the ion of the salt with acid-base properties?

Comment: Why for pKa you take the negative log of the ionization constant for acid? What the log represents? Why do this. I know the definition of log, just asking for the reason to take the negative log.

Comment: The negative log returns a positive pH value (generally), since concentrations of hydronium and hydroxide ion are typically very low, so they are expressed using negative exponents - i.e. $1.0 \times 10^-6$. The negative is mainly there for convention - it's a bit easier dealing with positive values in general.

Comment: Alright, then is my guess correct or not?

Comment: Why would you take the base part of the salt and see how much hydronium ion it creates? Why not hydroxide ion?

Comment: Only strongly acidic salts have anions that are part of weak acids

Answer (score 2):

**Steps for determining acidity or basicity of a salt by hydrolysis:**

1. Write the neutralization reaction in reverse (salt and water makes base and acid).
2. Break up the salt into its ions.
3. To write the base, add an $\ce{OH-}$ to the cation (the positive ion) for each + charge.
4. To write the acid, Add $\ce{H+}$ to the anion (the negative ion) for each negative charge.
5. If you for a strong base, the salt is **basic**.  $\ce{(NaOH, KOH, LiOH, Mg(OH)_2,  ...)}$

   If you form a strong acid it is **acidic**.  $\ce{(HCl, HNO_3, HClO_4, HBr,...)}$

   If you form both a strong acid and a strong base it is **neutral**.

**EXAMPLE:**

$\ce{NH_4Cl}$

$\ce{NH4Cl + H_2O <=> NH4OH + HCl}$

Since $\ce{HCl}$ is a strong acid it breaks up and yields $\ce{H+}$, the salt is **acidic**.

Comment: The MathJax module implemented here makes use of the [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) latex package. You can learn more about formatting in the [help]. I have formated your post with these style commands, if you want to have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Isnt NH4OH not really a real thing?